# Drop and Restore database on package failure using SSIS

Tags: ssis

Say for example I have an SSIS package with more than 20 steps doing an assortment of tasks and I wish to do the following when the package fails:

1.) Drop the database

2.) Restore the backup taken at the beginning

3.) Send an email containing the log file

At the moment I have added these steps into the `OnError` event at package level, and this works apart from the fact that it is generally doing this twice each time the package fails. I understand that the `OnError` may occur multiple times before the whole package terminates but I don't understand how I can do what I want any other way?

I essentially want to run the said steps on package termination i.e. it will run once not several times depending on the number of errors that caused the package to fail. I don't mind receiving two emails with the only difference being an extra error in one but I don't think it is right to drop/restore the database twice for no reason. I cannot see a suitable event for this?

Comment: How are you running your package? If in SQL Agent, the simplest solution would be to create a T-SQL job step that runs on failure of the package

Comment: Yes its a job invoked by a SQL Agent which picks up the DTSX from the file system. Is there no way to handle this internally to the package as I do not have access to the production server hence why I am trying to encapsulate as much as I can within the package itself.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put all the steps of your package in a container, changing the OnError handler to increment an ErrorCount variable, and putting another container that happens OnCompletion of the main container that checks the ErrorCount and performs the actions in your current OnError handler if the count > 0.